# Replace all characters in strings in database for others?

Tags: mysql

I want to replace all 'á' in table `Cities` and column `Domain` for 'a'.

EG:

```
ID   Domain
1    árbol
2    megá
```

RESULT:

```
ID   Domain
1    arbol
2    mega
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Cities
   SET Domain = REPLACE(Domain,'á','a');
```